# Is it possible to fetch images from S3 to Ec2?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have the website built in Ec2. I want to put all images in S3 and then they are served on the website which is on Ec2. So how do I go about fetching images to act as images in img src code on pages in ec2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-custom-origins.html

Comment: so it is no way for me to fetch images from S3 to Ec2?

Comment: Yes you can fetch from s3 to ec2. I'm using this tool s3cmd from my Linux box. If your'e using WinX, I think there's a port of the same tool.